# Detecting a Tilt event on google cardboard not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm trying to go back from one screen to another using Application.LoadLevel(0)
when the user tilts his head with the cardboard.

```
if(Cardboard.SDK.Tilted)
        //do whatever
```

However Cardboard.SDK.Tilted is always false  when I tilt the device in the unity editor using the mouse or when I build and run the app. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so turns out it was working. Just in case someone reads this, in Unity if u press control then move the mouse it will Tilt but it won't trigger the event as Tilted. To do that you have to press the Escape key and it will simulate a tilt event.